# AWS VPC Peering Connection breaking RDP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

Attempting to create a simple VPC peering connection between two VPC's with non-overallping subnets I've hit an odd situation - I am unable to access any EC2 instances in one of the VPCs via RDP.

I have since set this up using testing VPC's and instances with the following config:

VPC-TEST-A - 10.3.0.0/16 -- VPC-TEST-B - 10.1.0.0/16

One instance in each VPC - route table for each VPC is update with the relevant subnet. Security group applied to each Instance that allows RDp from our public IP. Each instance has an Elastic IP assigned. The peering request has been accepted as required.

RDP works to the instance in TEST-A but not at all for TEST-B - created another instance in B to check, and this is also inaccessible.

Can anyone see anything obvious, or not so obvious that I'm missing that is preventing RDP access to the instances in B?

Configuration screenshots added:

[VPC-TEST-B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROUDc.jpg)

[VPC-TEST-B-Route-Table[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLhHZ.jpg)

Comment: Are you attempting to connect to the EIP's from your VPC?  Are you attempting to connect from host in A to host in B (and the other way)?  Or something different?

Comment: At this stage I'm just attempting to RDP into an instance in VPC-TEST-B - from my public connection. I've not even attempted inter-connectivity at this stage as I can't administer the instances in the VPC. The other VPC instances, in VPC-TES-A are fine and I can connect to them without issue via RDP.

Comment: double check that the subnet in VPC B is public.   If you post some screen shots of your network, subnets, routes etc. that would be helpful.

Comment: The Subnet is definitely Public, nothing changed other than creating the Peering Connection between VPC-TEST-A and VPC-TEST-B. I have tried removing the Peering connection, without any effect on being able to access via the Elastic IP. Will add screenshots of the config to the main question.

Comment: Post the routing table.  Have you added/modified any NACL entries?

Comment: Looking at the routing tables there were multiple assigned to the TEST-B VPC which when removed allow me to RDP to the EIP of the instance! Looks to have resolved the issue.